# Map the Exception of a failed Future

Tags: scala, akka, future, scala-2.10

What's the cleanest way to `map` the `Exception` of a failed `Future` in scala?

Say I have:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val f = Future { 
  if(math.random < 0.5) 1 else throw new Exception("Oh no") 
}
```

If the Future succeeds with `1`, I'd like to keep that, however if it fails I would like to change the `Exception` to a different `Exception`.

The best I could come up with is transform, however that requires me to make a needless function for the success case:

```
val f2 = f.transform(s => s, cause => new Exception("Something went wrong", cause))
```

Is there any reason there is no `mapFailure(PartialFunction[Throwable,Throwable])`?

Comment: transform is the right way to go. you don't need to create the s => s function, just pass in ``identity``

Comment: Cheers. I didn't know about the `identity` function. I'm sure there will be more times where that will come in handy.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There is also:

```
f recover { case cause => throw new Exception("Something went wrong", cause) }
```

Since Scala 2.12 you can do:

```
f transform {
  case s @ Success(_) => s
  case Failure(cause) => Failure(new Exception("Something went wrong", cause))
}
```

or

```
f transform { _.transform(Success(_), cause => Failure(new Exception("Something went wrong", cause)))}
```

Comment: While this is a very clear syntax, we still have to `throw` the new exception, instead of getting to map `Throwable` to `Throwable`. Is there a combinator for just that?

Answer (score 17):

You could try `recoverWith` as in:

```
f recoverWith{
  case ex:Exception => Future.failed(new Exception("foo", ex))
}
```

Comment: Future.failed is not evaluated on an ExeecutionContext: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Future$ see ``failed``

Comment: @ViktorKlang, I must be confused then.  I had made this assumption in looking at the `impl.KeptPromise` class' `onComplete` method.  In there, there are the two lines `val preparedEC = executor.prepare; (new CallbackRunnable(preparedEC, func)).executeWithValue(completedAs)`.  I assumed this to imply that even though we were giving an explicit value that it still for some reason was hitting the executor.  It always seemed strange to me and I guess it's actually because I was misreading it.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. My only hesitation with using `recover`/`recoverWith` is that when I see it I immediately assume that the intention is to recover from a failure with a successful result. Maybe that is just me. Even so they are good alternatives, thanks!

Comment: @cmbaxter I still do not understand on how it doesn't hit ExecutionContext.

Comment: @cmbaxter - could you please check out my related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173982/dealing-with-a-failed-future.

Comment: @theon The fact that you use an exception or something else to signal to your program that something failed should not matter i think. Hence using recover or recoverwith should be the way to go i presume.

Comment: @MattDeomon Since it is a failure, I'd rather use an Exception, so it triggers `onFailure` callbacks rather than `onSuccess` callbacks. I think it is more intuitive that way. I still also find `transform` more intuitive than `recover` or `recoverWith`, because I am not recovering from a failure with a success, I am transforming a failure into another failure. That is true regardless of whether we use an `Exception` or a regular class to signal the failure.