# Does scala.concurrent.Future have this functionality out of box?

Tags: scala, future

So I often find myself writing this helper function and finally got sick of it and decided to ask about it. The functionality I want is to map a failed Future to another failed Future based on the exception "thrown".

Does Future have this functionality and I just haven't found it yet?

```
object FutureUtils {
  implicit class FutureWrapper[T](val fut: Future[T]) extends AnyVal {
    def mapFailure(f: PartialFunction[Throwable, Throwable])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = {
      val p = Promise[T]()
      fut onComplete {
        case Success(a) ⇒ p success a
        case Failure(e) ⇒ p failure f.applyOrElse(e, (t: Throwable) ⇒ t)
      }
      p.future
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at `recoverWith`? It's not exactly what you're asking for (you'd have to wrap the output in a `Future.failed`), but at least it'd simplify your implementation a bit.

Comment: I just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250888/map-the-exception-of-a-failed-future

Comment: I don't want to recover, only change the exception.

Comment: recoverWith looks like the closest thing to what I want. It's a shame about the Future.failed wrapper so I'll just stick with what I have.

Comment: Mapping an exception to another one is a little strange, so I don't think it's surprising that the standard library doesn't have anything to do it straight-away. `recover` and `recoverWith` both reduce it to one-liners, so I'd be pretty satisfied with that combined with the implicit class.