# Dealing with a Failed `Future`

Tags: scala

Given the following two methods:

```
def f: Future[Int] = Future { 10 }
def g: Future[Int] = Future { 5 }
```

I'd like to compose them:

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> import scala.concurrent.Future._
import scala.concurrent.Future._

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> for { 
     |   a <- f
     |   b <- g
     | } yield (a+b)
res2: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@34f5090e
```

Now, I'll call `Await.result` to block until it's finished.

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
```

As expected, I get `15`, since `Await.result` took a `Future[Int]` and returned an `Int`.

```
scala> Await.result(res2, 5.seconds)
res6: Int = 15
```

Defining a `recoverFn` for a failed Future:

```
scala> val recoverFn: PartialFunction[Throwable, Future[Int]] = 
    { case _ => Future{0} }
recoverFn: PartialFunction[Throwable,scala.concurrent.Future[Int]] = <function1>
```

I try to define a failedFuture:

```
scala> def failedFuture: Future[Int] = Future { 666 }.failed.recoverWith{ recoverFn }
<console>:20: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Any]
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[Int]
       def failedFuture: Future[Int] = Future { 666 }.failed.recoverWith{ recoverFn }
                                                                        ^
```

But, I get the above compile-time error.

Specifically, how can I fix this error? Generally, is `Future#recoverWith` typically how failed `Future`'s are handled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `Future#failed` *always* returns `Future[Throwable]`. It's purpose *is not* to simply fail a `Future`, but instead to return a *failed projection* of that `Future`. This means that if the original `Future` failed, it will be converted to a *successful* `Future` that holds the exception. And if the original `Future` succeeded, then it becomes failed, and holds a `NoSuchElementException`. The error you are getting is because you're essentially recovering a `Future[Throwable]` with a `Future[Int]`, which has a least upper-bound of `Future[Any]`.

If you're just trying to play with failed `Future`s, try this instead:

```
scala> Future.failed[Int](new Exception("???")).recoverWith(recoverFn)
res4: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@6933711b

scala> res4.value.get
res5: scala.util.Try[Int] = Success(0)
```

There is nothing wrong with `recoverWith`.